# Cloning Objects in Google Optimize

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-optimize

I'm trying to clone a button in Google Optimize (or any other javascript/jQuery method) that adds an item into a shopping cart.  My problem is that when I run the code or experiment in Optimize, the button doesn't trigger.

Here's my two different attempts. Method 1 via Optimizes' interface.

1. Select the button to copy, use the 'edit code' to get the html.
2. Use Insert HTML a the location of the new button, and insert the code.

Version 2 uses jQuery's `clone()`;

```
$('#SOME-ID > PATH TO THE ELEMENT TO CLONE').clone().attr('id', 'ADD-ID-FOR-GTM-TRACKING').appendTo('#proPriceMobile');
```

What could the problem be?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's likely that the HTML is cloned, but the event listeners are not?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Quite possibly.. how would I clone the event listeners?

Comment: Use a single delegated event handler for the dynamic content, or possibly `clone(true, true)`, although I've had mixed results with the latter.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've also had mixed results. I can't quite remember why and under which circumstances. I do remember it working not as I expected.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - could you please clarify a bit on the clone(true,true) method.  Appreciate.

Comment: Sure, it's all in the docs: https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents. As above though, I'd suggest that using a delegated event handler is a much more reliable approach.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan $('#SOME-ID > PATH TO THE ELEMENT TO CLONE').clone(true,true).attr('id', 'ADD-ID-FOR-GTM-TRACKING').appendTo('#proPriceMobile'); 

Gives me a 'hasAttribute' undefined error message.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible, that your experiment fires **BEFORE** your buttons loads on your page, in your actual browser.

Do you get an error message in console?

My tip would be to wait for your button to load, before applying the DOM changes.   If possible, do this all via JavaScript.

For example, here you can wait for an element to load, via using a callback and setTimeout():

```
// FUNCTION WHICH WAITS FOR YOUR INITAL BUTTON to LOAD
function waitForElement(className, callBack){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        // GRAB YOUR ELEMENT
        var element = document.querySelectorAll(className)[0];
        if(element) {
            callBack(className, element);
            console.log("Callback successfully fired and code executed...")
            
        } else {
            waitForElement(className, callBack);
            console.log("This runs every second until your element is loaded on the page..")
        }
    },1000)
};

// EXECUTE THE CODE IN THIS FUNCTION, WHEN YOUR BUTTON LOADS IN THE DOM
waitForElement(".your-element-classname",function(){
    console.log("Button has loaded in DOM...");
    // NOW CLONE YOUR BUTTON
});
```

When I've cloned buttons in the past, I've lost all functionality on the cloned button.  So you may need to rebuild that functionality on the cloned button.